# Filter a Dataframe using a subset of it and two specific fields in spark/scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, join, union

I have an Scala/Spark question. I'm using Spark 2.1.1.
I have a Dataframe that looks like this:

| client | transaction | amount | machine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0000001 | transaction1 | -0.010000 | user000000001 |
| 0000002 | transaction2 | 0.010000 | user000000001 |
| 0000002 | transaction2 | 0.010000 | user000000002 |
| 0000002 | transaction2 | 0.010000 | user000000003 |
| 0000003 | transaction3 | -0.010000 | user000000004 |
| 0000003 | transaction3 | -0.010000 | user000000002 |
| 0000003 | transaction3 | -0.010000 | user000000003 |
| 0000003 | transaction3 | -0.010000 | user000000011 |
| 0000001 | transaction4 | 0.010000 | user000000011 |

Also, I have another Dataframe, a subset:

| client | transaction | amount | machine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0000002 | transaction2 | 0.010000 | user000000001 |
| 0000002 | transaction2 | 0.010000 | user000000002 |
| 0000002 | transaction2 | 0.010000 | user000000003 |
| 0000003 | transaction3 | -0.010000 | user000000004 |
| 0000003 | transaction3 | -0.010000 | user000000002 |
| 0000003 | transaction3 | -0.010000 | user000000003 |
| 0000003 | transaction3 | -0.010000 | user000000011 |

How can I filter the first using the second one? I don't know if it's possible a substract option but using two fields as conditions to filter the dataframe. Or a way to perform a join/union but using two different conditions. Why to use two fields as condition? well, if you analize the table, you can see that the transaction2 and transaction3 are repeated n times with different machine identifiers. I need to preserve only the rows with a unique transaction where the machine match with the non-repeated transaction machine. I mean, I need a table like this:

| client | transaction | amount | machine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0000001 | transaction1 | -0.010000 | user000000001 |
| 0000002 | transaction2 | 0.010000 | user000000001 |
| 0000003 | transaction3 | -0.010000 | user000000011 |
| 0000001 | transaction4 | 0.010000 | user000000011 |

I would greatly appreciate your help and guidance with this!

Comment: What did you try so far? What is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to substract subset dataframe from first dataframe, you can use a left anti join, as follows:

```scala
dataframe.join(subset, dataframe.columns, "left_anti")
```

Given your input dataframe and your subset, you will get:

```
+-------+------------+------+-------------+
|client |transaction |amount|machine      |
+-------+------------+------+-------------+
|0000001|transaction1|-0.01 |user000000001|
|0000001|transaction4|0.01  |user000000011|
+-------+------------+------+-------------+
```

Then you can get the `machine` column and use an inner join to filter duplicates in your first dataframe. Complete code would be as follows:

```scala
dataframe.join(subset, dataframe.columns, "left_anti")
  .select("machine")
  .join(dataframe, Seq("machine"))
```

And you will get your expected result:

```
+-------------+-------+------------+------+
|machine      |client |transaction |amount|
+-------------+-------+------------+------+
|user000000001|0000001|transaction1|-0.01 |
|user000000001|0000002|transaction2|0.01  |
|user000000011|0000003|transaction3|-0.01 |
|user000000011|0000001|transaction4|0.01  |
+-------------+-------+------------+------+
```

However, in your case, I don't think you need to build the subset dataframe, you can get your result by using only first dataframe, as follows:

```scala
dataframe.groupBy("transaction")
  .agg(count("transaction").as("total"), first("machine").as("machine"))
  .filter(col("total") === 1)
  .select("machine")
  .join(dataframe, Seq("machine"))
```